# User deletion, suspension should remove the users from chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, deleted-users, account-suspension

There was recently quite a number of new users with the swastika as the avatar created by one spammer - they then joined into many of the rooms in the SO chat. Now the issue is that as a user is deleted, the icon still lingers in the room user list, until the chat is reloaded.

Wouldn't it be possible that if a user is deleted on the main site, then the user be removed from all the chat rooms right away, to limit the visibility of these spammers?

Addendum: if the account is suspended, the avatars are there even after reloading.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2157227#2157227

Comment: @balpha can the main site not trigger a leave event to the chat system  as part of the deletion process?